# What does the Shenanigans option do in Duck Game?

Tags: duck-game

It does not seem to do anything. I don't see a difference when I toggle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [a pinned topic on the Steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/312530/discussions/0/618463738399170603/):

> What does the shenanigans option do in the settings?
>   Turns off the little bleep sound that occurs when your duck gets hit by items.